# Format of sound/image files to be used in Android Apps

Tags: android, image, audio, voice

While developing an Android app what format of sound/image should i should be using so that i can control the overall size of the app after completion.

Comment: Thanks all for the inputs. I would like to know if i use mp3 as my sound file which is of 2 MB, will it again added to my app size as 2MB or will it compress.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

My choice would be:

1. Images: go with JPG for compression or PNG for quality and transparency support.
2. Audio: go with MP3-VBR (variable bit rate) for compression and quality.

The size of your file will be greatly affected by compression level. At some point, if you compress too much you will see/hear artifacts. The acceptable level of compression is subjective and really depends on the input data (image or audio). You should be testing different levels of compression to see what works.

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) is a link to all the media types supported by Android.
For sound I would probably use a low-bitrate `.mp3` or a `.midi` and for images either a compressed `.jpg` or `.gif`

Comment: Thanks all for the inputs. I would like to know if i use mp3 as my sound file which is of 2 MB, will it again added to my app size as 2MB or will it compress.

Comment: I don't think Android compresses it, so you would have to lower the actual mp3's bitrate / record with a low one. I don't know what OS you have, but in Windows you can check a mp3's bitrate by right clicking it, clicking `Properties` then `Details`

Answer (score 1):

For supported media formats see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

For images you'll probably end up with JPG or PNG (if you need transparency). You should also scrape the images to remove all unnecessary meta data etc. For linux, a nice tool for this is [Trimage](http://trimage.org/).